# how to add a voice search bar in my android app and how to give connection to any database to get output result

Tags: database, voice-recognition, voice, searchbar

Can you please any one  tell me how to add a voice search bar to my application,which is takes voice input pincode and which will gives the output address reslut from database ....i seen more applications used google voice search bar to give output result in the app.so please help me how to connect to any database to get the result from my voice search app...i am searching for it from 3 months plz help for my dream project.plz help me with detailed example and with mentioning database linking also.out put result should be with text and audio result ok.Thank you

Comment: Do you already have some kind of project started? If yes can you show us?

Comment: please check this application which is i geven in the link bellow.....i want a voice search plugin to my app which  PNR voice search bar  in this "where is my train app" 
 app  link:- https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.whereismytrain.android&hl=en